# Sum of Alternate Harmonic Series Invalid Method?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Let $f(x) = x - \dfrac{1}{2}x^2 + \dfrac{1}{3}x^3 - \dfrac{1}{4}x^4 + \cdots.$ Then $f'(x) = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \cdots = \dfrac{1}{1+x}.$ Integrating,
$$f(x) = \int f'(x)\,dx = \ln|1+x|+C.$$
Neglecting the constant term the alternate harmonic series evaluates as $f(1) = \ln2$ as expected, but why can the constant term be ignored? Is this method invalid?

Comment: You find the constant term by substituting a value of $x$.  If you set $x = 0$, you will see $C = 0$.

Comment: $f'(x)=1/(1+x)$ and $f(0)=0$. The initial value determines the constant.

Answer (score 1):

It should be $$f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t)\,dt = \ln|1+x|.$$